# Indent in a customized enviornment

Tags: sectioning, indentation

Hullo. I have a doc, and am using a customized environment. I have tried putting the title for the next section simply as a subsection, but like the customized environment I have created. However, I would like the text 'within' said environment to be indented (even the first paragraph) just like the rest of my doc (I use the package 'indentfirst'). Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Weekday Morning Prayers}
\section{Morning Prayers of Light}
\begin{prayerheading} 
  Tuesday Morning-Prayer V
\end{prayerheading}

O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc

For Thou art our God, and unto Thee do we send up glory: to the Father, and to the Son, and to the Holy Spirit, now and ever, and unto ages of ages. Amen. 

\end{document}
```

And for the *prayerheading*, I use the following environment:

```
\newenvironment{prayerheading}{% 
 \center\large\bfseries\color{red}%
 }
{\endcenter}
```

Thanks for any help you all can be!

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with indenting the text; is it perhaps something like this `\newenvironment{prayerheading}{\begin{quote}\center\large\bfseries\color{red}}
{\endcenter\end{quote}}`? If not, can you please explain in a little more detail your intent?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I use indent first for the entire document (to indent each paragraph under 'headers' by the normal amount), and wish to have the text under the \prayerheading 'header' indented just like the rest of the document.

Comment: But isn't that the current effect with your current definition if you leave a blank line between `\end{prayerheading}` and the following text?

Comment: Hi again. Wow, (I had *no* space between the end of prayerheading and the following text. Upon inserting a space, the indention appears. Gosh, I feel stupid now. Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options here:

1. Leave a blank line between `\end{prayerheading}` and the following text:

   ```
   \documentclass{book}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \newenvironment{prayerheading}
     {\center\large\bfseries\color{red}}
     {\endcenter}
   \begin{document}

   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   \begin{prayerheading}
   Tuesday Morning-Prayer V
   \end{prayerheading}

   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Add a `\par` after ending the environment (in this way, there's no need to explicitly give a blank line); notice that, in this case, it's necessary to use `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` instead of `\center`, `\endcenter`  in the definition of the environment:

   ```
   \documentclass{book}
   \usepackage{xcolor}

   \newenvironment{prayerheading}
     {\begin{center}\large\bfseries\color{red}}
     {\end{center}\par}

   \begin{document}
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   \begin{prayerheading}
   Tuesday Morning-Prayer V
   \end{prayerheading}
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

3. Use the `titlesec` package and customize a sectional unit heading to produce the desired layout; in the following example I used `\subsection*` (since the unstarred version for `\titlespacing` was used, the following paragraph will receive the standard indentation):

   ```
   \documentclass{book}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{titlesec}

   \titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
     {\normalfont\large\bfseries\filcenter\color{red}}{}{0em}{}
   \titlespacing{\subsection}
     {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

   \begin{document}
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   \subsection*{Tuesday Morning-Prayer V}
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   O Treasury of Good Things, Ever-flowing fountain, Holy Father, etc etc
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]